# How do you change the parent of a modeless dialog in MFC?

Tags: mfc, dialog, parent

Imagine I have model dialog A.

It creates a modeless dialog B.

Dialog A then displays a pop up modal dialog C.

Is it possible to temporarily set the parent of the modeless dialog B to the pop up C?

Does that make sense? At the moment it looks like the parent can only be set at creation time.

Comment: Try the [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) function. Or, in MFC, the `CWnd` class has [SetParent() member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#setparent).

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for that. I tried googling on my phone for **setparent** all lowercase and nothing was showing up. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You aren't actually trying to change the parent. You are trying to change the [owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows). That's not possible: *"After creating an owned window, an application cannot transfer ownership of the window to another window."*

Comment: @IInspectable I see, well I suppose I could keep track of when that popup modal is displayed so so I know we are working with it.

Comment: @IInspectable I now see that the easiest thing to do is have my own HWND variable in the modeless dialog that I can set. If it is NULL then it use the default parent (the owner if effect). But if it is not NULL (the popup model) then we postmessages to that window accordingly. That would work?

Comment: It is not clear: what are you trying to achieve by changing the parent or the owner?

Comment: @VladFeinstein The modeless dialog communicates with the main window. If a certain control in the main window gets focus, the list of names changes in the modeless window. In principle, if you click a name from that modeless window, it selects it in the control with focus. it is like a history log. If i display the popup window which has three different controls for assignments, when i set focus to one of those controls, i now want the modelless dialog to be working with that window control with focus, untiol the popup is closed, and it revert to working with the main dialog controls again.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle from what you said, you need a handle to some specific control in your `dialog B`. Could you just pass it to `B` in response to control activation (focus)?  If you handle a click in `B`, you'd need to return focus to that control anyway...

Comment: @VladFeinstein Yes